# Why am I unable to access class properties inside of a passed function of an Angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, geolocation

I am using HTML 5 geolocation inside an Angular component:

```
...
    export class AngularComponent {
    ...
        constructor(private db: DatabaseService) {}

        // this function is assigned to an HTML button
        logCoords(message, action) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.success, this.error, this.options);
        }

        success(pos) {
            function time() {
            ...
            }
            var crd = pos.coords;
            var lat = crd.latitude
            var long = crd.longitude

            let newCoordinates = {'lat': lat, 'long':long, 'time': time}
            this.db.addLocation(newCoordinates)
        }
    ...
    }
...
```

I want to store the result of the getCurrentPosition Method inside indexed db using an Angular service but I am unable to access any properties of the component class (this.db is null).

Why I am unable to access this.db inside the success function and how I might be able to work around this?

Comment: Can you share some code on stackblitz?

Comment: add code of module, I thing you forget to inject the service in module.

Comment: The module is injected and works in other parts of the template; Inside success, console.log shows that this.db is null. I figured it had something to do with my lack of understanding of javascript since the success function is being used elsewhere in the geolocation library...

Comment: Replace `success(pos) {` with `success = (pos) => {`

Comment: makes sense. wish I had a technical description of why that didn't work. may god bless you.

Comment: The reason is `scope`. There are a couple posts about that topic, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with the below line:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.success, this.error, this.options);
```

In above line, you are just passing `this.success` as callback without setting context to it. So in this case as per javascript principles, `this` would always refer to window object while you are expecting component reference.
To fix this, you have to set the context (component instance) before passing `this.success` and for that purpose javascript provided bind() function.

Try below code (very simple fix) -

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.success.bind(this), this.error.bind(this), this.options);
```

For more details around bind() function refer below link -

https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1):

Because you lose the context `this` when passing the method as a callback.
You can fix this by multiple ways:

```
logCoords(message, action) {
    // bind context
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.success.bind(this), this.error.bind(this), this.options);
}
```

or

```
logCoords(message, action) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.success, this.error, this.options);

    success = (pos) => {} // <= arrow function
    error = () => {}      // <= arrow function
}
```